# Why are UK MPs allowed to abstain (but it counts as a no)?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, parliament, house-of-commons, member-of-parliament

When reading the results of the recent call for a general election the numbers were 298 for, 56 against. The motion failed to pass due to not reaching the 2/3 majority. It took a little digging to realise that although 298 is much greater than 2/3 of 354 (298+56) the MPs that didn't vote are also counted. This doesn't make sense to me.

I can understand why abstaining from a vote is a allowed - if an MP doesn't feel like they have enough information or has no feeling one way or another on a subject - but why does an MP not voting essentially go in the against column? Is there a underlying rationale behind this (not specifically for a general election vote, but any vote that requires calculation in this way).

Comment: The real question seems to be: Why is there a quorum that needs to be met? And that is to avoid abuse. Otherwise, you could just make sure the other party ca't show up and then vote whatever you want.

Comment: Or to answer your question literally, as posed in the title: The MPs that don't vote are not counted and specifically their non-votes don't count as negative votes. You misunderstood the "2/3" part. This is more of an addition to any of the existing answers and doesn't stand on its own, so I post it as a comment.

Comment: @Polygnome Not really, because if that were a legitimate concern then the same logic would apply to the majority of other parliamentary business (it doesn't). The real reason is probably just to ensure a particularly high threshold

Comment: @Nobody That doesn't answer the question literally, because OP is right, requiring 2/3 seats does imply that abstention 'counts as' (pedantry about exactly what is being counted aside..) 'no'.

Comment: The title was ambiguous: I kept seeing it and thinking it was about the scenario where one side provides no tellers.

Comment: @Polygnome But that is not the question asked.

Comment: Any sensible constitutional referendum would also have a high threshold and be compared to the whole electorate not just those who turn up.

Comment: @JeremyFrench that seems unfair- people can vote no without voting, but you have to go vote for a yes?

Comment: "I can understand why abstaining from a vote is a allowed - if an MP doesn't feel like they have enough information or has no feeling one way or another on a subject" I think abstention is mostly because the MP isn't in London that day, for whatever reason.

Comment: @DavidRicherby There are plenty of reasons for abstaining, including not having an opinion on a bill or motion (and it not being a party vote), not willing to support the party vote but also not willing to vote against the party, and matched abstentions where one MP is unable to attend a vote for important medical or personal reasons and the major parties have an agreeement in place to cancel out those missing votes by having an opposite voting MP also abstain from voting.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Because the [Fixed Term Parliaments Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/14/enacted) law says so:

> if the motion is passed on a division, the number of members who vote in favour of the motion is a number equal to or greater than ***two thirds of the number of seats in the House (including vacant seats)***.

It's not about who votes and who doesn't, it's a legal requirement that there is a minimum threshold of the entire House which needs to be met.  In this case, it was not met.

Comment: Worth noting that this minimum threshold isn't only a requirement for a vote to have an election, it is isn't it?

Comment: @Pelinore what do you mean?  In this specific circumstance, the FTPA only has the two third majority restriction for an agreed early election motion under section 2.(1).  For a no confidence motion under 2.(3), there is no two third majority requirement, and for normal legislative bills there is also no two thirds majority requirement.

Comment: Ugh! my typo I meant ***"is"*** rather than ***"isn't"***, so yes, I did mean that :)

Comment: Does this mean that abstain-votes are for all intends and purposes nay-votes in this particular case, so the only difference between abstaining and voting against is symbolic?

Comment: @Philipp yes. In this case, the leader of the opposition has  called for an election over 30 times in the past 2 years. For him to turn around and vote against having an election a) breaks all precedent but b) makes him look like he doesn’t believe he can win.

Comment: @Philipp my opinion on that is “no”.  The law being applied sets a threshold for yes votes which must be met, regardless of no votes or abstentions. Yes votes are yes votes, no votes are no votes and abstentions are abstentions, and the threshold is either met or it isn’t.

Comment: @Moo: Interestingly, though, if an MP votes in both lobbies (as a "positive abstention" or to cancel a mistake), it's functionally equivalent to just voting in the yes lobby, since the count of ayes is the only thing that matters. The no count goes up by one, sure, but it makes no difference in the outcome.

Answer (score 14):

This is an exception to normal parliamentary procedure.  As @Moo correctly answers, the Fixed Term Parliament Act requires a specific threshold to pass.

Closure Motions also have a threshold of 100 (thanks @steve-melnikoff).

Normal contested votes in the House of Commons only require a majority of MPs who voted, provided minimum quorum (40 including the speaker) is met.  So theoretically 610 MPs could abstain and 19 vote against a bill and it would still pass.

If there are only MPs present on one side of the debate, it will pass/fail unopposed when voice votes are called.

Comment: The quorum of 40 is for a division (apart from closure motions, which require 100 MPs to vote in favour). There is no quorum for a voice vote, so it could in theory just be the Speaker to put the question, and one MP to shout aye or no. During adjournment debates, it's not unheard of for there to only be 4 people present: the Speaker (or a deputy), the MP who called the debate, the minister who responds, and a government whip.

Comment: Thanks @SteveMelnikoff I'd forgotten that division is not a given.  You've also answered a question I was contemplating regarding whether there are other motions with a threshold. updated

Answer (score 4):

If you watched the proceedings, you would have noticed that the speaker announced something akin to "So the ayes have it.  But I have to remind you that according to ...".  So the vote was put on record as being in favor of new elections but not gaining the necessary quorum of valid (yes) votes.

Answer (score 3):

Purposely avoiding mentioning the rules causing this, since @Moo already answered with that.
If there is no vote for a motion, it is not counted as a vote for that motion. (Circular, I know.)

The UK parliament is set up to maintain the status-quo in cases where there's a tie, or some uncertainty.

Also, if the majority was only out of people who showed up to the vote and voted, you could far more easily affect the outcome of a vote by preventing MPs from showing up to the vote. Whereas if this is to happen now, the status quo is maintained, and if it's a big enough issue, another attempt can be made to vote later.

Comment: This implies this is usual case for parliamentary votes, but the quorum for the house of commons is 40.  The abstentions only matter in the special case of the Fixed term parliament act.

Comment: Didn't know that, so I had a read of the 2011 FTP act. Is the 2/3 majority only the case when an election is being called? I didn't see it anywhere else in the. document. (Didn't check amended acts) Especially makes sense for calling a general election though.

Comment: Only when an election is called using FTP.  Vote of No Confidence can get an election with a simple majority.  Or a new Act Of Parliament which specifies 'Not withstanding the FTP' can also call an election.  There may be other special cases which require a specific threshold, but I am not aware of any.

Comment: Maybe worth explaining why... the point is that this fixed term law was brought in to stop governments from calling early elections at opportune moments to cash in on some moment of popularity. It is intended to restrict the government (not so much the opposition, hence a vote of no confidence only requiring normal majority). If all they needed to get around it was a normal majority, it wouldn't restrict them. A possible loophole that's therefore been mentioned is that the government could try calling a motion of no confidence in itself!

Comment: "if the majority was only out of people who showed up to the vote and voted, you could far more easily affect the outcome of a vote by preventing MPs from showing up to the vote": but normally it *is* only out of the people who show up to vote.  Given the quorum requirement of 40, a normal motion can pass on a vote of 21 in favor to 20 opposed.

Comment: @Rupe Unfortunately due to the principle of parliamentary sovereignty, all they need to get around it **is** a normal majority, even without considering motions of no confidence (see Phil's comment above). The FTP Act is more of a gesture than a legally binding rule. It relies on the government abiding by it for political reasons, but there is nothing to stop the govt. from passing a new Act (using a simple majority) with an express or implied partial repeal (which can be temporary if Phil's wording is adopted).

Comment: @phil Note that the "notwithstanding" wording is only needed if you want to call an election whilst simultaneously retaining the FTP provisions for future elections. Otherwise you can simply pass an Act that calls an election without referring to the FPT at all. Parliamentary sovereignty ensures that when two Acts conflict, the newer Act impliedly repeals the older Act to the extent of the conflicting sections. Indeed this is necessarily for a healthily functioning parliament as old as ours, otherwise you'd need to check the entire statute book for conflicts any time you pass a new Act.

Answer (score 3):

That’s the rules for this particular vote: Two thirds *of all MPs* must vote yes, not two thirds of all voting MPs.

But obviously the MPs are aware of the rules, so if the rules were different (two thirds of voting MPs) then most of the abstainees would have voted “No”.